# How to fix ERROR 29 (HY000) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

When I use this command below in Mysql client 5.1 in ubuntu:

```
load data infile 'words.csv' into table words;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/var/lib/mysql/bhuvan/words.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

Help me out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
load data local infile 'words.csv' into table words 
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n';
```

If your words file is in your / directory.

Comment: Worked for me. 'local' is the key word.

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu users,

Check you currently use: [mysql -u user -p --local-infile](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1990780).

Another [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile) talking about apparmor configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is located on your client machine, you should use this:

```
load data local infile 'words.csv' into table words;
```