# MySQL - Partition DB tables into different EBS volumes in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an Amazon EC2 Server instance and it is attached with five EBS volumes say

1. ebsvol1
2. ebsvol2
3. ebsvol3
4. ebsvol4
5. ebsvol5

while provisioning this server I need to install MySQL Server and need set up my Database.  Here I need to mount few tables to one EBS volume (say ebsvol1) and other tables to another volume (say ebsvol2).

I am beginner to this Amazon env.  Please guide me how to proceed.

Comment: I don't think mysql supports that.

Comment: Why is it you want to put each table on a different volume?

Comment: @Omry : The data on few tables grows largely, when users count raises.  The spreading of tables into different volumes is of interest.

Comment: @Omry : The spreading of tables into different volumes to improve the IO performance and everything else.

Comment: I would like to use 'MyISAM' storage engine of MySQL Database server there I can tables with DATA Directory and Index Directory options, there I can specify different volumes for each table.   I am not sure this is right solution for my problem?

Comment: The correct approach to scale up size and performance is to use a raid configuration with multiple volumes underneath - not to split based on table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer applies to LINUX-based instances.

Start with [this article at Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663) which explains how to set up MySQL to run on an EBS volume. This is not strictly necessary - the following steps should work fine with a standard MySQL installation.

You will need to create a new **schema** for each EBS volume / group of tables. I don't believe you can keep your tables in one schema, but spread them over multiple EBS volumes. Each empty schema is represented by a folder in **/var/lib/mysql/** containing a single file named **db.opt**.

To move a schema to it's own EBS volume requires the following steps (using schema **my_schema**):

- mount the EBS volume if not already mounted (assuming mounted as **/ebsvol1**); make sure the volume is listed in **/etc/fstab** so it will get automatically mounted on reboots
- change permissions of the mounted folder to match the current schema folder

> ```
>    chmod 700 /ebsvol1
>    chown mysql /ebsvol1
>    chgrp mysql /ebsvol1
> ```

- copy the **db.opt** file from the schema folder to the new volume (if you have already created tables under the schema, those too need to be copied)

> ```
>    cp /var/lib/mysql/my_schema/db.opt /ebsvol1/
>    chmod 660 /ebsvol1/db.opt
>    chown mysql /ebsvol1/db.opt
>    chgrp mysql /ebsvol1/db.opt
> ```

- replace the original schema folder with a symbolic link to the EBS volume

> ```
>    cd /var/lib/mysql
>    rm -fr my_schema
>    ln -s /ebsvol1 my_schema
> ```

If your operating system uses AppArmor, you may need to include /ebsvol1 in the list of folders MySQL is allowed to write to. See [the article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile) for details.

Now any tables created under **my_schema** will be stored on /ebsvol1.