# Can't save csv to local folder [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm on a localhost, with root access.

I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file 'C:\Users\mypath\full customer table.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

This is the code:

```
select * from customer
into OUTFILE 'C:/Users/mypath/full customer table.csv'
fields terminated by ',';
```

Have tried granting privileges but to no avail:

```
GRANT All privileges ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Is MySQL running as a service? That could explain your issue? Create a folder C:\export and try again with 'C:\export\mytable.csv' as target.

Comment: Why will it running as a service change things? I tried what you said, didn't work :(

Comment: Because MySQL will run as an other user and have the rights of this user and not your rights. Folders under C:/Users are usually only writable for the logged on user.

Comment: It's got to be a problem of Windows file system rights. Is MySQL running as a service? If yes, which user does it uses? And what version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists already you'll need to delete before running your MYSQL code - you can't over-write a file on disk with MYSQL.

You could create a batch file to delete the file first, then have your MYSQL code run.

Comment: no, there's no file there at all :( I'm trying to create a new file. Maybe I'm using the wrong commands altogether?

Comment: Possibly similar?: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile)