# MYSQL OUTFILE Folder

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, plesk, into-outfile

I'm running an Ubuntu Server with Plesk and I need to export a file (xls) from MySQL using OUTFILE. I have this query:

> SELECT * FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'xxxxxx.xls'

The file is saved into folder /var/lib/mysql/

I can create other folders inside mysql folder too and it works, but the question is, how can i save the file into a folder outside mysql folder, something like /var/www/something/ ?

If I try this example I get MySQL Errcode: 13 (Can't create/write to file).
I researched this into MySQL docs and this could be a permissions issue (See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html). I checked the permissions on the folder and everything seems to be correct. Anyone have more information on how to solve this problem?

Comment: How about `select * from table into outfile '/var/www/something/xxxxx.xls'`?

Comment: Hi Jashaszun, that's what causes the error to which I refer (Errcode: 13).

Comment: I tryed this solution too but nothing:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile?rq=1
Maybe something with Plesk?

Comment: A workaround solution was posted in the thread posted by @Martín, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/22500728/863923