# MySQL export to file

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a `node js` project with folder `output`. This folder has 777 permissions. I query `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` via `node-mysql`.

But I have `Errcode: 13 - Permission denied` error.

`MySQL` started with `secure_file_priv=""`

SQL:
`SELECT * FROM users INTO OUTFILE '/home/ubuntu/Projects/output/1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Comment: good to know? what about the code?

Comment: @LelioFaieta, I added my sql query

Comment: try to change the url of the file as relative to the root folder of your project and not as an absolute url

Comment: @LelioFaieta, mysql changes it to `/var/lib/mysql/output/`

Comment: @Tryam Check this similar question which may help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile

Comment: i pretty sure your MySQL server is configured to allow making a file in one directory only to prevent possible backdoors (webshells generating codes) from happing when SQL injections are possible with `‘ union select “<? system($_REQUEST[‘cmd’]); ?>”, <match_columns> INTO OUTFILE ‘/var/www/test/execcmd.php’#` (PHP example pretty sure it's also possible with Node.js) and would allow making the file everywhere.